# Is protobuf-net compatible with Windows azure (web role)?

Tags: c#, serialization, azure, protobuf-net, azure-web-roles

I'm building some wcf services for inter web role communications
and i'm looking at getting some performance enhancments.  Built in .net serialization is well known for being lacking in the speed deparment.

I have been looking into protobuf-net for the serialization for across the wire and for caching purposes.

My question is - Will the protobuf-net library play well with the cloud? I believe that the web role runs in partial trust by default.

Comment: Windows Azure roles run in full trust by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used it and can vouch that the protobuf-net works well. Specifically, I've used it for storing data in the queue, as its limit is 8192 bytes (the limit is actually lower, due to I think UTF8 encoding ~ 6.3k). Anything larger you need to store the data in the BLOB and a reference in the queue.

As for using it to serialize WCF data, I am sure it will work as well, but I dont have experience in that space.